# PHPMailer failed occasionally

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email, but it fails sometimes.

```
$email = new \PHPMailer();
$email->isSMTP();
$email->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username = '...';
$email->Password = '...';
$email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$email->Port = 25;
$email->From = '...';
$email->FromName = '...';
$email->Subject = '...';
$email->addAddress( '' );
$email->Body = '...';
$email->isHTML( true );

if ( !$email->send() ) {
     echo $email->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I get `The following From address failed: ... : Called Mail() without being connected` error.

Note, sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not.

Comment: how could i possibly know where your mail logs are ?

Comment: @xuc Do you use window or linux?

Comment: I can't see how it is working sometimes. `tls` have to be used with port `587`, `25` and `465` use `ssl` (this is gmail specific, not global rule)

Comment: gmail has limit. you can not send as many as you want. read here more http://www.serversmtp.com/en/limits-of-gmail-smtp-server.

Comment: It's not bulk sending. I am sending about 150 per hour one by one.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I tried them all. Only tls/25 is working.